# Making navigation right aligned

Tags: css, navigation, alignment

I have 
having a hard time making my navigation right aligned. Please help Here is my code:

```
.site-nav {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.site-nav ul {
  margin: 62px;
  text-align: right
  background-color: #000;
}

.site-nav li ul {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 200px!important;
}

.site-nav li {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Please add your markup as well.

Comment: Please post the HTML as well

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the site-nav code:

`.site-nav {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;/* change left to right */
   }`